# Sudden "No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted. To request a free parallelism grant" error on old organisation

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, pull-request

I suddenly got this error on a pull request so it cannot build.

We have 1 parallel job in our self-hosted project on Azure DevOps and NONE is running currently so not sure why would this error appear at all?

Also [according to the info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted)  they "have temporarily disabled the free grant of parallel jobs for public projects and for certain private projects in new organizations".

Our organisation is not new, we've been on Azure for years.

Any thoughts?

Comment: For some reason your account got flagged. Reach out to Azure Support to have them reinstate the free grant. And make sure you haven't reached the 1800 free minute limit.

Comment: I have no idea how to contact their support, I cannot find such option in Azure DevOps @jessehouwing

Comment: Fill in this form and wait 24h: https://forms.office.com/pages/responsepage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR63mUWPlq7NEsFZhkyH8jChUMlM3QzdDMFZOMkVBWU5BWFM3SDI2QlRBSC4u

Comment: I did, that's not support, that's a request form for more parallel jobs which is don't really need. I just need the devops to work as it'd been working so far

Comment: You can open a support request here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/devops/ scroll down past the self-help options to find the link to open an Azure Support Request.

Comment: Cool thanks, I'll see if they help

Comment: I have received the reply from them already @jessehouwing and it's all fixed. Thanks

Comment: Request a free parallelism for private repo, it takes 12-24 hours to get approval. The link to the form for sending request shows up in the pipeline run-error log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have received several feedback recently. Some customers' free parallel job were banned after February 8th.

As jessehouwing said, I suggest that you re-apply for free parallel job through [this form](https://forms.office.com/pages/responsepage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR63mUWPlq7NEsFZhkyH8jChUMlM3QzdDMFZOMkVBWU5BWFM3SDI2QlRBSC4u) first. Also, you can contact Microsoft Support by [Azure DevOps Services support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/devops/) or [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=21). They may help you speed up your application progress.